# My hook setCalculation is not considered a function. Why is this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a calculator app and when I test it, I get an error saying "setCalculation is not a function". I don't know what the problem is, and I have worked on other applications where I used hooks and I've never gotten this error. I don't understand why this isn't working so any explanation would be appreciated. If posting more code is necessary I'll be sure to do it.

```
let { calculation, setCalculation } = useState("");
let { result, setResult } = useState("");

const operations = ["/", "x", "+", "-", "."];

const updateCalculation = (value) => {
    if ((operations.includes(value) && calculation === '') ||
        (operations.includes(value) && operations.includes(calculation.slice(-1)))
    ) {
        return;
    }
    else if(value === '+/-' && value.parseInt() > 0){
        value = "-" + calculation;
    }

    setCalculation(calculation + value);

    if (!operations.includes(value)) {
        setResult(Function(calculation + value).toString());
    }
}
```

I'm simply trying to set the updated calculation value, and I tried googling fixes for this problem but all the examples I could find involved using multiple components. All of my code is in one App.js file. I'm not using any external components.

Comment: `useState` returns an array, not an object, so use `let [calculation, setCalculation] = useState("")` and `let [result, setResult] = useState("")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using object destructuring:

```
let { calculation, setCalculation } = useState("");
let { result, setResult } = useState("");
```

It should be array destructuring since output of `useState` is an array:

```
const [ calculation, setCalculation ] = useState("");
const [ result, setResult ] = useState("");
```

NOTE: `const` is more appropiate instead of `let` since we don't change the value directly.

Comment: Thank you so much! That WAS the problem